# Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am getting these error

Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

my code is shown below

projectname.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('learning.urls',namespace='learning')),
  ]
```

app_name.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from learning.views import SendEmail

urlpatterns = [
   path('',SendEmail.as_view(),name='home')
]
```

Comment: You should add  `app_name` attribute to learning.urls. Check [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#id5)

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution:

```
from django.urls import path
from learning.views import SendEmail

app_name = "learning"

urlpatterns = [
    path('',SendEmail.as_view(),name='home')
]
```

Comment: Note that once you have added `app_name`, you can remove `namespace='learning'` from `include()`. You only need to set `namespace` if you want it to be *different* from `app_name`.